# Micro meter symbol changed

Tags: luatex, siunitx

I'm facing a curious problem with the micrometre symbol. When using the `\micro \meter` macro of the `siunitx` package with the below code, I get the strange symbol depicted in the image for all the occurences.

```
\SI{50}{\micro\meter}
```

I'm compiling with `luatex`. All other measure units are compiled correctly.
Does someone have already experimented this issue or has a clue about the cause?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Update: as suggested by the comments the problem resided in including `[T1]{fontenc}` package. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal *compilable* example? From `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are using an inappropriate font setup. Almost certainly you have T1 selected for font encoding.

Comment: Are you loading the `fontenc` and/or `inputenc` packages? If so, don't do that.